# Editing an /etc/fstab entry in C++

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems, mount

I'm trying to edit the `/etc/fstab` file on a CentOS installation using C++.  The idea being that based on another config file I will add entries that don't exist in the fstab, or edit entries in the fstab file where the mount point is the same.  This lets us set the system up properly on initial bootup.

I've found `setmntent()` and `getmntent()` for iterating over the exiting entries so I can easily check whether an entry in fstab also exists in my config file.  And I can then use `addmntent()` to add any entry that doesn't already exist - the documentation says nothing about this being able to edit an entry, only add a new entry to the end of the file.  There seems to be no way to edit an existing entry or delete an entry.  It seems odd that this feature doesn't exist, only the CR and not the UD of CRUD.

I'd rather not have to write my own parser if I can at all help it.

My other alternative is to:

- open the file using `setmntent()`
- read the whole of fstab into memory using `getmentent()` and perform any additions and/or edits
- close the file using `endmntent()`
- open `/etc/fstab` for writing
- close `/etc/fstab` (thus emptying the file)
- open the fstab using `setmntent()`
- loop through the entries I read in previously and write them out using `addmntent()`

Which although probably fine, just seems a bit messy.

Comment: move the current file to a backup instead of truncating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When modifying system configuration files such as `/etc/fstab` keep in mind that these are critical state and, should your "edit" be interrupted by a power loss, might result in a failure to reboot.
The way to deal with this is:

1. create an empty output:
   `FILE* out = setmntent("/etc/fstab.new", "rw");`
2. open the original for input:
   `FILE* in = setmntent("/etc/fstab", "r");`
3. copy the contents:
   `while (m = getmntent(in)) { addmntent(out, m); }`
4. make sure the output has it all:
   `fflush(out); endmntent(out); endmntent(in);`
5. atomically replace `/etc/fstab`:
   `rename("/etc/fstab.new", "/etc/fstab");`

It's left as an exercise to the reader to change the body of the while loop to make a modification to an existing element, to substitute a specifically crafted `mntent` or whatever. If you have specific questions on that please ask.

UN*X semantics for `rename()` guarantee that even in the case of power loss, you'll have either the original version or your new updated one.

There's a reason why there is no `modifymntent()` - because that would encourage bad programming / bad ways of changing system critical files. You say at the end of your post "... probably fine ..." - **not**. The only safe way to change a system configuration file is to write a complete modified copy, sync that to safe storage, and then use rename to replace the old one.

Comment: That is what I was intending to do, I was just keeping it simple to illustrate the point.I think not having a `modifymntent()` encourages bad ways of doing things because people will be writing their own parsers and doing the kind of things you've just warned about.  Much better to have the function there that does that all for you.

Comment: The original question stated you had planned to actually _write_ `/etc/fstab`. That's the key step to avoid, as mentioned. Write a **new** file. As you say, the `*mntent()` functions are not usable for anything else but pure input-only / output-only. That's what I've been trying to state: It's by design/intent ! Hence the use of two files - read from `/etc/fstab`, write to `/etc/fstab.new`, when done flush that and rename. In C++-speak, you'd call `getmntent()` a const forward input iterator, and `addmntent()` a forward output iterator. Note: neither random nor bidirectional.

Comment: If you look at it from the point of iterator traits, then it's also clear that a const forward input iterator means you cannot _modify_ the file you iterate over through that. For the mentioned pattern, input and output can't be the same file.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, when I say write I meant that was the ultimate goal, to have a new fstab.  I understand that it's designed for input / output only.  I still think that not having a modify function and leaving the way of doing it up to the programmer to do any old rubbish, instead of encapsulating all you suggested in one easy function call is a Bad Thing.